# Connecting to Google Cloud AI Platform Notebook instance with custom docker image results in "Connection refused"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-notebook, google-dl-platform

I'm am trying to launch a Notebook on Google Cloud AI Platform using a custom image. I followed the practice described here:

https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/deep-learning-containers/docs/derivative-container

So to build and push the docker image:

```
gcloud auth configure-docker
export PROJECT=$(gcloud config list project --format "value(core.project)")
docker build . -f Dockerfile -t "gcr.io/${PROJECT}/my-custom-image:latest"
docker push "gcr.io/${PROJECT}/my-custom-image:latest"
```

However, when trying to connect to a Notebook instance using this image

```
gcloud compute --project "myproject" ssh --zone "myzone" "custom-test" -- -L 8080:localhost:8080
```

I get

```
ssh: connect to host XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX port 22: Connection refused
```

This happens even if I just use the base image without any changes, e.g. with this
Dockerfile:

```
FROM gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/base-cpu:latest
```

If I launch a Notebook instance based on `gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/base-cpu:latest` directly I am able to connect to it as expected.

EDIT 1:
From Serial Port 1 log:

```
May  9 16:51:31 custom-test GCEGuestAgent[673]: 2020-05-09T16:51:31.7524Z GCEGuestAgent Info: Updating keys for user MYUSER.
[  206.144111] google_guest_agent[673]: 2020/05/09 16:51:33 logging client: rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = The caller does not have permission
May  9 16:51:33 custom-test google_guest_agent[673]: 2020/05/09 16:51:33 logging client: rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = The caller does not have permission
May  9 16:53:25 custom-test ntpd[707]: kernel reports TIME_ERROR: 0x41: Clock Unsynchronized
```

Seems to be a permission error, but I'm not sure why I would not have permission to deploy an image I pushed from same account. Could it be related to `custom-test ntpd[707]: kernel reports TIME_ERROR: 0x41: Clock Unsynchronized`?

EDIT 2:
Now, about an hour later, I can connect (with no changes made). But when accessing `localhost:8080` I get:

```
channel 4: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
```

as output in the attached console.

From Serial Port 1 log:

```
May  9 18:04:36 custom-test systemd[1]: Started Session 4 of user MYUSER.
May  9 18:04:36 custom-test GCEGuestAgent[673]: 2020-05-09T18:04:36.5636Z GCEGuestAgent Info: Updating keys for user MYUSER.
May  9 18:04:37 custom-test google_guest_agent[673]: 2020/05/09 18:04:37 logging client: rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = The caller does not have permission
[ 4590.862794] google_guest_agent[673]: 2020/05/09 18:04:37 logging client: rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = The caller does not have permission
```

EDIT 3:
Launching the image as a VM results in:

```
[   26.315675] konlet-startup[535]: 2020/05/09 19:34:57 Launching user container 'gcr.io/myproject/my-custom-image:latest'
[   26.315713] konlet-startup[535]: 2020/05/09 19:34:57 Configured container 'instance-1-test' will be started with name 'klt-instance-1-test-azmb'.
[   26.315740] konlet-startup[535]: 2020/05/09 19:34:57 Pulling image: 'gcr.io/myproject/my-custom-image:latest'
[   26.839555] konlet-startup[535]: 2020/05/09 19:34:57 Error: Failed to start container: Error response from daemon: {"message":"pull access denied for gcr.io/myproject/my-custom-image, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: Permission denied for \"latest\" from request \"/v2/myproject/my-custom-image/manifests/latest\". "}
[   26.839839] konlet-startup[535]: 2020/05/09 19:34:57 Saving welcome script to profile.d
```

Comment: Try to add more verbosity on your command, that may give some more hint:   
`gcloud compute --project "myproject" ssh --zone "myzone" "custom-test" -- -L 8080:localhost:8080 --verbosity=debug`

Comment: I have some additional questions:    
1. Can you run the command 'gcloud container images list' This information will help to identify if the issue is with your access to the repository.   
2. Can you authenticate again using 'docker login' from the VM and try to pull the image again? This will help to determine if the issue is with the docker authentication.   
3. Can you also try to create the container manually using 'docker run' command and let me know if it works. If not, can you specify the error you are getting.